# Swift Parse PFQuery filter tableA and filter pointer tableB

Tags: swift, pointers, parse-platform, pfquery

here’s my concern:

I have a table A which contains a set of properties including a location property (FYI, no pointers in the table)
I have a table B which contains a set of properties and a pointer pointing to a unique object in table A (using the table A objectId property). There may be a same pointer for several objects in table B.
So basically, each object in table A has several objects pointing to it from table B.

What I’m trying to achieve is to filter all elements from table A within a certain location using: (please note generic names in the code examples)

```
let queryA = PFQuery(className: "tableA")
queryA.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: location, withinMiles: 5)
```

which works fine, and then to get all elements from table B pointing to the filtered elements .. and here is a first problem, because table A has no pointers, there seem to be no way to achieve this directly from table A, is there ?

So what I’ve tried is start filtering all objects in table B according to the filtered objects from table A, which led me to:

```
// Filtering all objects in table A according to a specific PFGeoPoint.
let queryA = PFQuery(className: "tableA")
queryA.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: location, withinMiles: 5)

// Filtering all elements in table B according to filtered elements from table A
 let queryB = PFQuery(className: "tableB")
 queryB.includeKey("pointer")
 queryB.whereKey("pointer", matchesKey: "objectId", in: queryA) 

// and then fetch the objects
queryB.findObjectsInBackground() { objects, error in
print(objects)
}
```

which doesn’t work because it seems that matchesKey must be operating under the same class.

I’ve then tried to find all objects from table A within a certain location using queryA and use a for-loop to iterate through the result of the method findObjectsInBackground with Block — [PFObject] —  and at each iteration running another findObjectsInBackground using objectId from each PFObject element and passing it to queryB using whereKey and a

```
 PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: <>, objectId: <>)
```

which works but leads to asynchronous problems and doesn’t seem quite proper to me.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to model the relationship between tableB and tableA objects by assigning a relation to tableA (not an objectId) to tableB.  In other words...

```
var tableAObject = PFObject(className:"tableA")
// setup tableAObject

var tableBObject = PFObject(className:"tableB")
// setup tableBObject
tableBObject["pointer"] = tableAObject  // not tableAObject["objectId"]

tableBObject.saveInBackground()  // this will save both objects
```

With that, you'll be able to make the relational query using `whereKey:matchesQuery:`...

```
let queryA = PFQuery(className: "tableA")
queryA.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: location, withinMiles: 5)

let queryB = PFQuery(className: "tableB")
queryB.whereKey("pointer", matchesQuery: queryA)
queryB.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {}
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong (really new to this), the queries I've implemented in my initial post won't work because I haven't correctly setup the relation between tableB and and tableA before, right? So when you write: tableBObject["pointer"] = tableAObject, that literally means "each value for each row under the pointer property will refer to tableA (not an objectId specifically). What will this do when firing saveInBackground(), replace the values the in pointer property ? If so, how to retrieve a specific row in tableA using using "queryB.whereKey("pointer", matchesQuery: queryA)" ?  thanks.

Comment: Basically, I need to replace all the objectId values referring to tableA under the "pointer" property from tableB ? then how to get the matching items using a specific filter ?

Comment: @Julm - `tableBObject["pointer"] = tableAObject` means: "assign a reference to a particular object in tableA (tableAObject) to the 'pointer' property of a particular object in tableB (tableBObject)".  By implication, when tableBObject is saved, the tableAObject to which it refers will be saved, too.

Comment: but then how to make them match ? since we're assigning a reference of a whole table to tableBObject["pointer"] and not of a specific property (such as objectId)? In other words, all my values under "pointer" in tableB will have the same tableAObject (the whole table) as references, right?

Comment: I guess the part I don't get is what this tableAObject stands for.

Comment: tableA and tableB are collections of objects (tables in SQL language).  tableAObject and tableBObject are individual instances of objects (in SQL, you might say that tableAObject is a row in tableA).  `tableBObject["pointer"] = tableAObject` means we're taking a particular, singular object and assigning a reference to it to another particular, singular object.

Comment: Alright I get it so I guess I just need to replace current references to tableA objects using their objectIds by references to tableA objects using another property? Right ?

Comment: Yes.  And it's a good idea to use another property, named differently.  Once you get it working you can delete the "pointer" column.  The first few paragraphs of this section of the docs is good reading for this....https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relational-data

Comment: Now I m confused with that part in the documentation: « you can also link objects using just their object Ids like so ». One question : when assigning tableAobject to tableBObject[« pointer »] what will appear in the value fields instead of the objectsIds ? Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about that aside.  It's still saying you should assign an object to the property.  That line of code says, in the case where you only have an object's id, create an object out of it (withoutDataWithClassName:withId) and assign that object.

Comment: Thanks! Two last questions though to be sure I've understood everything: basically, if I assign a tableAObject (so basically a whole object with a set of properties, from table A ) to tableBObject["pointer"], the pointer value will be a whole object instead of just the objectID like before "EIj7767x", just out of curiosity what will appear in the value field instead of the objectId ? And when using: queryB.whereKey("pointer", matchesQuery: queryA), this will find all the filtered-by-location objects from table A that matches the PFObject from "pointer" in tableB. Is that right ? thanks again.